# SimpleJpaRepository Count Query

Tags: spring, jpa, repository

I've modified an existing RESTful/JDBC application i have to work with new features in Spring 4... specifically the JpaRepository. It will:

1) Retrieve a list of transactions for a specified date. This works fine

2) Retrieve a count of transactions by type for a specified date. This is not working as expected.
The queries are setup similarly, but the actual return types are very different.
I have POJOs for each query

My transactions JPA respository looks like:

```
public interface MyTransactionsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTransactions, Long> 
//My query works like a charm.

@Query( value = "SELECT * from ACTIVITI_TMP.BATCH_TABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(last_action, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ?1", nativeQuery = true )
List< MyTransactions > findAllBy_ToChar_LastAction( String lastActionDateString );
```

This returns a list of MyTransactions objects as expected. Debugging, i see  the returned object as ArrayList. Looking inside the elementData, I see that each object is, as expected, a MyTransactions object.

My second repository/query is where i'm having troubles.

```
public interface MyCountsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyCounts, Long> 
    @Query( value = "SELECT send_method, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM ACTIVITI_TMP.BATCH_TABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(last_action, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ?1 GROUP BY send_method ORDER BY send_method", nativeQuery = true )
    List<MyCounts> countBy_ToChar_LastAction( String lastActionDateString );
```

This DOES NOT return List as expected.

The object that holds the returned data was originally defined as List, but when I inspect this object in Eclipse, I see instead that it is holding an ArrayList. Drilling down to the elementData, each object is actually an Object[2]... NOT a MyCounts object.

I've modified the MyCountsRepository query as follows

```
ArrayList<Object[]> countBy_ToChar_LastAction( String lastActionDateString );
```

Then, inside my controller class, I create a MyCounts object for each element in List and then return List
This works, but... I don't understand why i have to go thru all this?
I can query a view as easily as a table.
Why doesn't JPA/Hibernate treat this as a simple 2 column table? send_method varchar(x) and count (int or long)
I know there are issues or nuances for how JPA treats queries with counts in them, but i've not seen anything like this referenced.
Many thanks for any help you can provide in clarifying this issue.

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour when you're doing a "group by".  It will not map to a specific entity.  Only way this might work is if you had a view in your database that summarized the data by send_method and you could map an entity to it.